# What is the Accessibility Label of Camera Snap Picture Button?

Tags: ios, accessibility, kif

As the title says, I am wondering what the accessibility label of the camera snap button is (as I need it for my integration tests with KIF), as depicted as the white button at the bottom of this image:

[image: iPhone camera view]

I tried looking up how to enable the accessibility inspector on my device, but couldn't find it. And Googling didn't do me any good.

Comment: why don't you use the accessibility inspector to check the name of the accessibility label you want?

Comment: Because I wasn't aware of it? Provide me a reference to some documentation on how to use it **on a device**, write it as an answer and if its valid I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accessible name is "Take Picture"

Comment: That was it! Out of curiosity... how did you know? Is it mentioned somewhere in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should activate the accessibility inspector. This [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/TestingAccessibilityOfiOSApps/TestAccessibilityiniOSSimulatorwithAccessibilityInspector/TestAccessibilityiniOSSimulatorwithAccessibilityInspector.html) contains a tutorial about how to do it. Once this is activated, you can use it to check the names of whatever accessibility label you want, so you should navigate to the screen this element it is and then open the accessibility inspector (tapping on the X icon). After that you should select the element which accessibility label you want to know.

You should close the accessibility inspector while navigating to the screen you want to check the accessibility label. Otherwise, navigating with the accessibility inspector open is kind of annoying.

Comment: This is only valid for the _iOS Simulator_ not for the _device_. I need the device to determine that because the camera view is only accessible via device, not simulator.

Comment: Oh sorry,  I thought you were using the simulator.

Comment: Do I guess I should remove my answer,  shouldn't I?

Comment: No, leave your answer up. There will be others that could benefit from knowing about how to do it in the iOS simulator and this could help them.